# Completion of a local ring, Vakil 29.3A

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $p$ is a point of $X$, which is a $\bar{k}$ variety of dimension $1$, $p$ is a node if the completion of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ at $m_{X,p}$ is isomorphic to $\bar{k}[[x,y]]/(xy)$. If now $\text{char}(\bar{k}) \neq 2$, show the curve $y^2-x^2-x^3$ has a node at the origin.

So we need to compute the completion of the local ring $(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3))_{(x,y)}$ at the maximal ideal generated by $x,y$. I kind of guess it is $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2)$, but do not know how to prove this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $x+1$ has a square root.  Use the usual Maclaurin power series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$, and you'll see that the only denominators are powers of 2.